# WebSocket Middleware for SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, websocket, signalr

We are trying to create a web socket middleware for logging.  SignalR does not seem to do any logging unless you have Debug set, which we don't want on all the time.  We'd like to create a middleware so we can capture messages pushed over the socket and log them as requests in Application Insights.

We're finding that we are unable to hook into the web socket initialization and messaging.  Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: If you'd like to capture and log all incoming messages, you can try to inject ILogger<YourHubName> in your hub server and write logs with messages within your hub methods' code logic.

Comment: I'm trying to set up a cross-cutting solution so I don't need to re-write the same code for every hub method.  While this would work, it would be a lot of repetitive code

Answer (score 0):

You can turn server side  logging as you can see on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-3.1). This will enable tracing for your SignalR hub.

Also if you want some custom logging, you just inject the logger via DI like:

```cs
private ILogger<INotificationsHub> Logger
{
    get
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<IYourHub>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to set up a cross-cutting solution so I don't need to re-write the same code for every hub method. While this would work, it would be a lot of repetitive code

Comment: You just configure it on the `appsettings.json` once.

Comment: As I said in my initial question, I don't want debugging on all the time.  I want to log hub op invocations as requests so I can track them without logging at a debug level.  Debug logging has a lot of data and using App Insights, that can get expensive

Comment: I belive the only way is to inject the logger then, I can't see another option. Wait maybe someone will answer like what you want then...